# Map nested json field

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I have json like this:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "address": {
    "city": "New York"
  }
}
```

How can I deserialize it to the follow dto using Jackson?

```
final class PersonDto {
  private final String name; // name
  private final String city; // address.city

  public PersonDto(String name, String city) {
  this.name = name;
  this.city = city;
 }
}
```

Essentially I am interesting, is it possible to map nested field 'city' in json using just constructor and annotations, or should I write custom deserializer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to solve my problem in appropriate way is using @JsonCreator annotation with @JsonProperty. So then the code will look like:

```
final class PersonDto {
  private final String name; // name
  private final String city; // address.city

  public PersonDto(String name, String city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public PersonDto(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("address") Map<String, Object> address) {
    this(name, address.get("city"))
  }
}
```

Of course it's the best way if you deserialize merely simple POJO. If you deserialization logic is more complex, it's better to implement your own custom deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only the JSON library for implementing such code.

```
public class AddressPojo {

private String city;
private long pincode;

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public long getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}

public void setPincode(long pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

}
```

and now the Main Layer

```
public class MainLayer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    AddressPojo addressPojo = new AddressPojo();
    addressPojo.setCity("NYC");
    addressPojo.setPincode(123343);
    json.put("name", "John");
    json.put("address", addressPojo);
    System.out.println(json.get("name")); // To Retrieve name
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json.get("address")); // To retrieve obj                                                                    // address                                                                  // obj
    System.out.println(jsonObj.get("city"));
}

}
```

That's it. Hope it helps:)